# JDBC connect with ProgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect my ProgreSQL DB, which runs on my PC, with JDBC.

```
package postgres;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;


public class SQLConnector {
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
Properties props = new Properties();
Connection con;

public SQLConnector() throws SQLException {
    props.setProperty("user", "postgres");
    props.setProperty("password", "admin");

    this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
}
public boolean isOpen() throws SQLException {

    return con.isValid(5);

}
public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException {
    SQLConnector sqldb = new SQLConnector();
    if (sqldb.isOpen()) {
        System.out.println("Connection successfully established.");
    }
}
}
```

I always get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection.isValid(I)Z
at postgres.SQLConnector.isOpen(SQLConnector.java:21)
at postgres.SQLConnector.main(SQLConnector.java:27)
```

The Driver is in Referenced Libraries of the project.

Would be happy about help.

Timon

Comment: Apparently the method `isValid(int)` is not implemented by the driver. Sounds as if you are using an outdated version of the driver.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome Timon.

Unfortunately, "jdbc3" method "isValid" is not implemented.

I suggest you use the "jdbc4".